# How to change lines in an react array?

Tags: reactjs

An array mapping is showing the image slider.

I'd like to change the strings to a string,

but I don't know how.

```
const data = [
  {
    path: slider_01,
    title: 
    `
    it is
    my first
    test
    `
  },
  {
    path: slider_02,
    title: 
    `
    it is
    my second
    test
    `
  },
 }
]

const ImageSlider = () => {

  return (
    slideData.map(img => {
         return (
           <div key={img.path}>
             <SliderImage src={img.path} alt={img.path}/>
             <p className="title" color='black'>{img.title}</p>
           </div>
         );
      })
    );
 };
```

My first thought was to use

```
`text${<br/>}`
```

but it didn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with data include `<br/>` tag

```
const data = [
  {
    path: slider_01,
    title: 
    `
    it<br/>
    is<br/>
    test
    `
  },
  {
    path: slider_02,
    title: 
    `
    it<br/>
    is<br/>
    test2
    `
  },
 }
]
```

then render:

```
...
<div key={img.path}>
         <SliderImage src={img.path} alt={img.path}/>
         <p className="title" color='black' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: img.title
              }}></p>
       </div>
<div
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<p className="title" color='black'>{img.title.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")}</p>
```

This will replace the newlines with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print the words on separate lines? If yes, this could be achieved with CSS, using the `word-spacing` CSS property, which specifies the space between each word.

```
<div key={img.path}>
  <SliderImage src={img.path} alt={img.path}/>
  <p style={{ wordSpacing: '100vw' }}className="title" color='black'>{img.title}</p>
</div>
```

I have forked a demo over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-agnesi-q4b8m).

Comment: oh, it is not words. my mistake. just custom

Comment: @minimin_bamm Hmm.. What is the output that you want? Do you want all of it to be on a single line..? Or separate lines?

Comment: The output that I want,

hi i'm <br> dev <br> test

Answer (score 0):

```
<p className="title" color='black' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: img.title}}></p>
```